# Sub-Domain Masking via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**EDITED**

I set-up a wildcard subdomain dns zone on my server and would like to have each subdomain load the contents of the /users/ direcotry using .htaccess and mod-rewrite.

I would like the URL to remain unaltered in the browser bar so that it shows:

```
http://username.domian.com/../../
```

while showing the contents of:

```
http://www.domain.com/users/username/../../
```

Additionally, I would like to redirect (change the URL) to the subdomain version if the www version of the URL is accessed.

I'm not overly familiar with mod-rewrite rules and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/users/%1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

If user will visit `tom.domain.com/directory1/directory2/directory3/file.html` he will be redirected (URL will be changed in browser) to `www.domain.com/users/tom/directory1/directory2/directory3/file.html`.

If that is not what you really after (as I'm a bit confused about this "masked" concept of yours) then please explain your requirements better so I can adjust the rule.

---

**UPDATE:**
To keep URL unchanged in browser:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/%1/$1 [L]
```

There one *problem* though: if `directory1` will be called `users` (e.g. `tom.domain.com/users/directory2/directory3/file.html`), then this will not work -- that is the price you have pay for rewriting. **Solution:** rename `users` to something unique (e.g. `users_dir_123_abc` etc -- `www.domain.com/users_dir_123_abc/tom/users/directory2/directory3/file.html`).

Comment: @dSquared See updated answer -- I have not tested on a live server, but should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. It works a charm when clicking on links within the pages; however when typing URLs directly into the browser it redirects to username.domain.com/users/username/../../ Any ideas?

Comment: What other rules do you have? It should not redirect if you ONLY have these rules. Plus .. it should work regardless if URL is typed or clicked -- so it's definitely other rule .. or some custom code (sounds like checking page referral?)

Comment: Appears the rewrite rule is only firing when the URL has a trailing slash on directories and not when there isn't one. How can I have it fire in both cases? All other rules have been commented out.

Comment: The rule itself does not case if there is a slash or not, so it should work in both cases. But any way -- try adding this directive `DirectorySlash Off` (I'm assuming you do not have opposite one).

Comment: Thank you for all your help; adding a /? to the RewriteRule fixed the problem like this: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/%1/$1/? [L]. I have a feeling this isn't the best way... =)

Comment: That `?` at the end will drop any existing query string. But if it's working then why not.

Comment: Sorry to revive this after so many years. How should I indicate that besides redirecting to the folder, I want to get to the https version of the subdomain? i.e. redirect `http://subdom.example.com` to the url `https://subdom.example.com` in the browser AND show the content of `https://example.com/subdomains/subdom/`

Comment: @DiegoDD That would be 2 separate rules: 1) Ensure that HTTPS is used first (redirect if not); 2) show what you need. I'm not using Apache now .. so would not be able to provide ready solution (nothing to test it on).