# .htaccess with subdomain masking and https redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to:

A: Redirect any http:// urls to https://

B: redirect my subdomains to certain folders each, while keeping the url in the browser untouched (masking)

(I already have the SSL certificates, for the whole domain and any subdomain)

My current structure is roughly

```
public_html/.htaccess [A]
public_html/sucursales/subdom1/.htaccess [B]
public_html/sucursales/subdom1/<otherfiles>
public_html/sucursales/subdom2/.htaccess [B]
public_html/sucursales/subdom2/<otherfiles>
...
```

I have 2 different .htaccess files, one under public_html directly [A] and other inside every subdomain folder [B] (each subfolder has the exact same [B] file)

Currently, i have managed to achieve A with a .htaccess file [A] containing:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mysite.com.mx/404.htm
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And i have achieved B with .htaccess [B] containing:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sucursales/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sucursales/%1/$1 [L]
```

I managed to make the [B] file based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590572/1385198

The problem is that if I go to `http://subdom1.mysite.com.mx` (non secure) it does show the content of the subdomain folder, and keeps the url in the browser (maskning), but it doesn't redirect to `https://subdom1.mysite.com.mx` (secure), so the browser reports it as not secure.

If I manually enter `https://subdom1.mysite.com.mx` it shows correctly, keeps the url (masking), and obviously shows as secure.

Now, what do I have to do to achieve that any subdomain redirects to its https version, while keeping the masking?

Which .htaccess should I modify and how.
Better yet, can I have everything in a single .htaccess file?

I have tried to modify [B] file by changing the last part
from

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sucursales/%1/$1 [L]`

to

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com.mx/sucursales/%1/$1 [L]`

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish all of this is going to be creating `Virtual Hosts` records at the server level.  This will take care of pointing each subdomain to it's respective directory.  --  At that point you'd have an `.htaccess` file in each directory that simply forwarded the `non-http` domain to `https`

Comment: @Zak Any reference of how can I do that? I'm using godaddy shared hosting, with cPanel, and also CLI access to the server.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: @Zak I'm not sure, i guess Apache, but how could I know for sure? As I mentioned, I'm using godaddy